# How to extract the number from the following string?

Tags: import, string-manipulation, data

Consider an archive a.gz with the file a.hepmc containing the following strings:

```
HepMC::Version 2.06.09
HepMC::IO_GenEvent-START_EVENT_LISTING
E 0 -1 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 9999 0 8 1 2 0 2 9.2276999999999998e-06 9.2277000000000001e-10
N 2 "Weight" "Weight_MERGING=0.000" 
U GEV MM
C 1.4764320000000000e-08 9.2276999999999998e-06
V -1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
P 1 -14 2.2204460492503131e-16 1.1102230246251565e-16 1.2000799696508180e+01 1.2000799696508182e+01 0 4 0 0 -1 0
P 3 -14 -2.2204460492503131e-16 -2.2204460492503131e-16 1.1999137831260905e+01 1.1999137831260906e+01 0 21 0 0 -3 0
V -2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
P 4 2 2.7755575615628914e-17 5.5511151231257827e-17 -1.9237084348915223e-01 1.9237084348915270e-01 0 21 0 0 -3 1 1 501
V -3 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0
P 5 -13 -6.6281670112489788e-01 -9.8089033408347626e-01 4.2181070223246007e+00 4.3823581225377515e+00 1.0566000000000000e-01 1 0 0 0 0
P 6 88288 6.3691118352999987e-01 -1.2709601074000015e-01 3.8562503376955561e+00 3.9156705579796549e+00 2.0000000000000001e-01 23 0 0 -5 0
P 7 1 2.5905517593898086e-02 1.1079863448234764e+00 3.7324096277515983e+00 3.8934799942326563e+00 0 23 0 0 -6 1 1 501
V -4 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0
P 2 2212 1.1102230246251565e-16 0 6.2525520240885868e-05 9.3827000208332656e-01 9.3827000000000005e-01 4 0 0 -4 0
P 8 2 4.7584182704973887e-01 -2.1470334414825987e-01 1.4836561334337106e-01 5.4271108850034955e-01 0 61 0 0 -2 1 1 501
P 11 2101 -3.9565176614831254e-01 2.4060781888312954e-01 2.4696733604229504e-01 7.8169594890584149e-01 5.7933000000000001e-01 63 0 0 -7 1 2 501
V -5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
P 9 88288 8.7826348504435525e-01 -2.1577135307561388e-01 4.1534653367271543e+00 4.2554880248174074e+00 2.0000000000000001e-01 1 0 0 0 0
V -6 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
P 10 1 1.8020498222885534e-01 9.5605386827595995e-01 3.3806606616870916e+00 3.5178657370832305e+00 0 62 0 0 -7 1 1 501
V -7 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0
P 12 111 -4.3152115639170679e-01 9.6583823629820531e-01 2.8393475710537559e+00 3.0330130624113920e+00 1.3497999999999999e-01 2 0 0 -8 0
P 13 2112 2.1607437247224953e-01 2.3082345086088432e-01 7.8828042667563070e-01 1.2665486235776802e+00 9.3957000000000002e-01 1 0 0 0 0
V -8 0 -7.6895751142628974e-05 1.7210942166415136e-04 5.0596305881463774e-04 5.4047365744409111e-04 0 2 0
P 14 22 -1.2594850084303760e-01 4.4220350681792725e-01 1.1853667518448099e+00 1.2714170451452178e+00 0 1 0 0 0 0
P 15 22 -3.0557265554866919e-01 5.2363472948027812e-01 1.6539808192089462e+00 1.7615960172661744e+00 0 1 0 0 0 0
E 1 -1 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 9999 0 8 1 2 0 2 9.2276999999999998e-06 9.2277000000000001e-10
N 2 "Weight" "Weight_MERGING=0.000" 
U GEV MM
C 2.9528640000000000e-08 0.0000000000000000e+00
V -1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
P 1 -14 6.9388939039072284e-18 5.5511151231257827e-17 1.2000799696531828e+01 1.2000799696531828e+01 0 4 0 0 -1 0
P 3 -14 0 8.3266726846886741e-17 1.1999137831235418e+01 1.1999137831235419e+01 0 21 0 0 -3 0
V -2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
P 4 2 -1.7347234759768071e-18 0 -1.0601058147964548e-01 1.0601058147964595e-01 0 21 0 0 -3 1 1 501
V -3 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0
P 5 -13 -7.9349437590920668e-02 -1.9844874980367261e-01 1.1041584956351216e+00 1.1296053552581322e+00 1.0566000000000000e-01 1 0 0 0 0
P 6 88288 -8.9381420427999991e-01 1.0728978402999999e-01 3.4244426894672046e+00 3.5464380246911511e+00 2.0000000000000001e-01 23 0 0 -5 0
P 7 1 9.7316364187392046e-01 9.1158965771672679e-02 7.3645260646534476e+00 7.4291050327657828e+00 0 23 0 0 -6 1 1 501
V -4 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0
P 2 2212 0 1.3877787807814457e-17 6.2525522090073338e-05 9.3827000208332767e-01 9.3827000000000005e-01 4 0 0 -4 0
P 8 2 -8.1113906255315893e-01 6.1818026952855287e-01 2.2884149812641779e+00 2.5053815180343975e+00 0 61 0 0 -2 1 1 501
P 11 2103 6.8439045879303662e-01 -4.6232884975821997e-01 5.9629440566363012e-01 1.2777539874840718e+00 7.7132999999999996e-01 63 0 0 -7 1 2 501
V -5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
P 9 88288 -1.1874467925185317e+00 3.2071777645727217e-01 3.8620937505284285e+00 4.0581594245506167e+00 2.0000000000000001e-01 1 0 0 0 0
E 2 -1 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 9999 0 10 1 2 0 2 9.2276999999999998e-06 9.2277000000000001e-10
N 2 "Weight" "Weight_MERGING=0.000" 
U GEV MM
C 4.4292959999999999e-08 0.0000000000000000e+00
V -1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
P 1 -14 1.6653345369377348e-16 5.5511151231257827e-16 1.2000799696579444e+01 1.2000799696579444e+01 0 4 0 0 -1 0
P 3 -14 1.1102230246251565e-16 4.4408920985006262e-16 1.1999137831184088e+01 1.1999137831184088e+01 0 21 0 0 -3 0
V -2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
P 4 2 2.7755575615628914e-17 5.5511151231257827e-17 -1.9775722413733243e-01 1.9775722413733285e-01 0 21 0 0 -3 1 1 501
V -3 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0
P 5 -13 3.4587000448583866e-01 9.6504980709725119e-01 4.4607778881807576e+00 4.5782803096210545e+00 1.0566000000000000e-01 1 0 0 0 0
P 6 88288 5.8755429212999999e-01 8.0034418860000234e-02 2.6691643210425524e+00 2.7415440407057470e+00 2.0000000000000001e-01 23 0 0 -5 0
P 7 1 -9.3342429661583859e-01 -1.0450842259572508e+00 4.6714383978234455e+00 4.8770707049946198e+00 0 23 0 0 -6 1 1 501
E 582 -1 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 9999 0 14 1 2 0 2 9.2276999999999998e-06 9.2277000000000001e-10
N 2 "Weight" "Weight_MERGING=0.000" 
U GEV MM
C 8.6075985600000833e-06 0.0000000000000000e+00
V -1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
P 1 -14 -1.1102230246251565e-16 -5.5511151231257827e-17 1.2000799696516506e+01 1.2000799696516506e+01 0 4 0 0 -1 0
P 3 -14 -5.5511151231257827e-17 -4.1633363423443370e-17 1.1999137831251931e+01 1.1999137831251932e+01 0 21 0 0 -3 0
V -2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
P 4 2 -2.7755575615628914e-17 -6.9388939039072284e-18 -1.8082389755369466e-01 1.8082389755369460e-01 0 21 0 0 -3 1 1 501
V -3 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0
P 5 -13 -4.6339668732005174e-01 -1.6657508227096424e-01 1.0478832552614381e+00 1.1626293906959710e+00 1.0566000000000000e-01 1 0 0 0 0
P 6 88288 1.3694731687300521e+00 -3.7869447970035740e-02 6.0526154839722714e+00 6.2089487879819067e+00 2.0000000000000001e-01 23 0 0 -7 0
P 7 1 -9.0607648136000019e-01 2.0444453023999995e-01 4.7178151944645244e+00 4.8083835501277470e+00 0 23 0 0 -4 1 1 501
V -4 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0
P 8 1 -1.5467696979106241e-01 -3.2486788262894917e-01 2.3269203856889544e+00 2.3545748209565129e+00 0 51 0 0 -8 1 1 502
P 9 21 -7.5139951156893814e-01 5.2931241286894914e-01 2.3351665728322564e+00 2.5095369651145472e+00 0 51 0 0 -9 2 1 501 2 502
V -5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
P 10 2 2.7755575615628914e-17 5.5511151231257827e-17 -2.3655213349700821e-01 2.3655213349700865e-01 0 53 0 0 -2 1 1 501
V -6 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0
P 2 2212 -5.5511151231257827e-17 0 6.2525520890144293e-05 9.3827000208332534e-01 9.3827000000000005e-01 4 0 0 -6 0
HepMC::IO_GenEvent-END_EVENT_LISTING
```

Shortly, it has a structure

```
    E ...
    N ...
    U ...
    C XXe-YY 0.0000000000000000e+00
    V ...
    P ...
    ...
    E ...
    N ...
    U ...
    C XXlaste-YYlast 0.0000000000000000e+00
    V ...
    P ...
```

Could you please tell me whether it is possible to extract the number XXlaste-YYlast after the last C row in the file, without unzipping it, and convert it to a number?

**Edit.**

Here is a brute-force method.

```
file=Drop[Import[
   FileNameJoin[{"a.gz"}],"Table"], 1];
fileC = Select[file, #[[1]] == "C" &];
fileC[[Length[fileC]]][[2]]
```

Comment: Do you *really* need to post the entire file?  Won't a two-line example suffice?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork : this is not the entire file, just a few events E ... .

Comment: Gee... you miss the point entirely.  There are numerous *useless* and irrelevant lines from your file—ones that have no bearing whatsoever on the question at hand.  You never answered my question:  "Won't a two-line example suffice?"  Well... what's your answer?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork : I don't agree with you. The "useless" lines may be important when coming up with solutions. Different solutions may work well for a "two-line" file, but once the "useless lines" get inserted, they may fail since the solution may process these lines incorrectly.

Comment: Anyway, I have already come up with an ugly solution to my problem.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork : I also do not understand what problem do you have with the file. It does not have a million strings, it may be easily copied to the clipboard...

Answer (score 0):

This is really a long comment, so please don't downvote.

The OP sees no problem with posting a portion of a file containing 6550 characters, nearly all of them useless, and asks:

- Could you please tell me whether it is possible to extract the number XXlaste-YYlast after the last C row in the file, without unzipping it, and convert it to a number?

I believe the question can be asked in full if the posted file contains these lines and these lines only:

```
E 0 -1 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 -1.0000000000000000e+00 9999 0 8 1 2 0 2 9.2276999999999998e-06 9.2277000000000001e-10 N 2 "Weight" "Weight_MERGING=0.000"

C XXlaste-YYlast 0.0000000000000000e+00
```

Actually, even less can be posted, without loss.

Paring a problem to its minimal form is explicitly encouraged on this site as it better helps reveal the structure of a problem, avoids wasting time reading and scrolling, and so on.

Comment: "nearly all of them useless"
Useless for what? I do not understand. 1) The file may be easily copied into the clipboard. The number of characters... Does any character cost electricity? 2) The "useless" strings may interfere with the solution proposed for the short file containing only E and C strings. It is unpredictable. Therefore, I kept a few of them. 3) I have shown the explicit structure of the file: "Shortly, it has a structure...". So no significant effort on scrolling is required.

Comment: Yes:  "nearly all of them useless."  Useless for the problem at hand.  Do you *really* think that specifying numbers such as -1.0000000000000000e+00 are "useful"?  Really?  If anyone takes the time to wade through this problem and gives you a solution, test it out on files that do NOT have, oh, the first 30 lines, and see if that makes a difference.  It won't.  Or turn it the other way:   using your logic, why didn't you cut and paste, or say, 1000 lines of a file?  That can be copied too.

Comment: "Do you really think that specifying numbers such as -1.0000000000000000e+00 are "useful"?"
It would be stupid to manually replace -1.000... with -1. However, both -1.00... and -1 may be important for the solution. Next, why not include 1000 lines? Because I needed a minimal sample exactly reproducing the file structure.

Comment: You wrote:  "3) I have shown the explicit structure of the file: 'Shortly, it has a structure...'.  So no significant effort on scrolling is required."  Now you're headed in the right direction!  Just keep going!

Comment: Actually, I have included this shorthand structure in the very beginning, not after your comment.

Comment: Exactly!   My point precisely!  *THAT* is all that was needed.  See?

Comment: No, I don't. According to what you wrote, there is no problem with my question.

Comment: Nope.  According to what I wrote (and you finally agree), the 6550 characters are indeed "useless" as the full question could have been posed with the shorthand structure.  Oh... ever wonder why nobody has answered your question?

Comment: Because I have already answered it.